# container of directive has 0px height, 0px width - angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When creating a directive the following way, the element itself (`<a-directive>`) has 0px height, 0px width. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLjja01j/)

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).directive('aDirective', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:red;"></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      }
    };
  });
```

And the html:

```
<a-directive></a-directive>
```

How do I get the html element to have its children dimension?

**EDIT:**

I just see that in the fiddle, it has a dimension. But in my project it generally has not. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: I think I found the reason. The <div> in the template has `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add CSS for your directive. Example:

```
a-directive {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. I had faced same issue and from my observation, when you set display(block or anything else relevant in your context) for directive element it reacts to the height/width changes.

Answer (score 1):

Add `replace:true` in your return object from the directive, and the directive will replace the div.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I like that it makes your markup more readable if you don't. I think there's a W3C `Layout` Class which different `Element` / `HTMLElement` concrete classes inherit from. I also know that the native WebComponents API allows for inheritance of certain `Element` / `HTMLElement` concrete classes. Anyone know if Angular has anything like this?